# Poor performance when at least one of the left joins should match a record

Tags: mysql, join

I've got bookings (`bookings`) in my database. A booking can have 0 to n flight services (`flight_services`) and 0 to n hotel services (`hotel_services`). A user on my website can filter the bookings by setting where conditions on each of these tables.

When `SELECT`ing, only bookings that have at least one flight service **or** at least one hotel service should be returned. Furthermore, there's a `flight_pivot_table` and a `hotel_pivot_table` and only the services should be considered that have a fix id (here `82`) in those pivot tables.

The query:

```sql
select `bookings`.*
from `bookings`
left join (
    select `flight_services`.*
    from `flight_services`
    inner join `flight_pivot_table`
        on `flight_services`.`id` = `flight_pivot_table`.`flight_service_id`
    where `flight_pivot_table`.`some_id` = 82
) as `flight_services`
    on `bookings`.`id` = `flight_services`.`booking_id`
left join (
    select `hotel_services`.*
    from `hotel_services`
    inner join `hotel_pivot_table`
        on `hotel_services`.`id` = `hotel_pivot_table`.`hotel_service_id`
    where `hotel_pivot_table`.`some_id` = 82
) as `hotel_services`
    on `bookings`.`id` = `hotel_services`.`booking_id`
where (
    flight_services.id is not null or
    hotel_services.id is not null
)
group by `bookings`.`id`
```

Unfortunately, this is extremely slow, although all indexes are used. With the data I've got, this query takes about 300 ms to execute. Here's the output of `EXPLAIN`:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | bookings |  | index | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 |  | 35173 | 100 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | flight_services |  | ref | PRIMARY,flight_services_uq | flight_services_uq | 4 | my_db.bookings.id | 2 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | flight_pivot_table |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | const,my_db.flight_services.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | hotel_services |  | ref | PRIMARY,hotel_services_uq | hotel_services_uq | 4 | my_db.bookings.id | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | hotel_pivot_table |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | const,my_db.hotel_services.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |

One of the following actions reduces the time to about 3 ms but obviously break the functionality:

- Remove the `INNER JOIN` from one or both of the sub queries.
- Remove the `WHERE` conditions.
- Replace the `or` with `and` in the `WHERE` conditions.

Notes:

- As it should be possible to add where conditions for `flight_services` and `hotel_services`, the aliases given for the left join sub-queries match the table names.
- I use `GROUP BY` because every booking should returned only once, of course.

How can I accelerate this?

Comment: Perhaps you can try `where exists` instead of the joins? Also, you shouldn't `select flight_services.*` when all you need is `booking_id`.

Comment: Thanks, but using `WHERE EXISTS` would take away the possibility to set `WHERE` conditions on those tables. The user should be able to filter the bookings by flight and hotel services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever possible, it is *usually* better to use `JOINs` rather than "derived tables".  (There are cases where the opposite is faster.)

That is, instead of

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... a JOIN b ... )
    JOIN ...
```

do

```
SELECT ...
    FROM a
    JOIN b ...
    JOIN ...
```

That being said, I see that you may have the "explode-implode" case:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM x
    JOIN z        -- explode
    GROUP BY x.id   -- implode
```

The `JOIN flight_services` seems to be 1:many -- hence "explode".  But you are not using any of the data from that table???  Why `JOIN` to it?  Why fetch all the columns, only to throw them away?

The pattern

```
LEFT JOIN z  ON blah
...
WHERE z.id IS NOT NULL
```

can be replaced by

```
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM z WHERE blah )
```

if you don't actually use any of the data from `z` (ie, `flight_services`).

This "semi-join" is faster because it stops once a match is found.  It does not do the "inflate", thereby helping obviate the need for the `GROUP BY`.

Ditto for the other `LEFT JOIN`.

I'm confused by the `JOIN` inside your derived tables.  Anyway, it can also be done in the `SELECT` inside the `EXISTS`.

Here is my suggested code

```
select  b.*
    from  `bookings` AS b
    WHERE  EXISTS 
        ( SELECT  1
            from  `flight_services` AS fs
            inner join  `flight_pivot_table` AS fpt  ON fs.`id` = fpt.`flight_service_id`
            where  fpt.`some_id` = 82
              AND  b.`id` = fs.`booking_id` 
        ) 
      AND EXISTS (... hotel_services join ...)
      -- no WHERE
```

Suggested indexes:

```
fs:  INDEX(booking_id, id)
fpt:  INDEX(some_id, flight_service_id)
```

Both the reformulation and the composite indexes should help speed things up.

**OR not AND**

Oops, I misread the original query.  `OR` is usually an Optimization killer.  But rewriting the query to use `UNION` may be the answer.

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE ... -- checking flight_services
) UNION ALL
( SELECT ...
    WHERE ... -- checking hotel
)
```

So you want to show cases where there are flight services but no hotel services?  And vice versa?

(Note:  `UNION ALL` should probably be `UNION DISTINCT` because there could be the same 'booking' from both?)

Anyway, let's work toward another optimization.  Since you want just the bookings and nothing about the flight and hotel, lets start by finding the `booking.id` values, *then* reach for `bookings.*`

This should give you the booking.ids based on flight stuff:

```
        SELECT  fs.`booking_id` 
            from  `flight_services` AS fs
            inner join  `flight_pivot_table` AS fpt
                ON fs.`id` = fpt.`flight_service_id`
            where  fpt.`some_id` = 82
```

Then, to finish

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM (
           ( that query
           )
           UNION DISTINCT
           ( a similar query, but for hotel
           )
         ) AS u
    JOIN bookings AS b  ON u.booking_id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer, Rick! When using your suggested code, one is not able to filter on `flight_services`/`hotel_services` anymore. I've tried it anyways and set your suggested indexes: Surprisingly the query still takes 300 ms to complete. The only difference is that I have connected the `WHERE EXISTS`' with `OR` instead of `AND` (`WHERE EXISTS(...) OR EXISTS(...)`), because that is how it is supposed to work. (And again, changing it to `AND` reduces the time to about 5 ms, but breaks functionality.) Why is `OR` so slow here?

Comment: @quick-brown-fox - Ouch.  `OR` is deadly for performance.  (I may have missed "OR" when I wrote my answer.)  I'll suggest turning `OR` into `UNION`; come back in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your update! To answer your question: I'd like to show only bookings that have at least one flight service and/or at least one hotel service (with the `82` in their respective pivot tables). And your `UNION` query does just that and is incredibly fast (5 ms)! However, filtering on both service tables is still not possible. To solve that, I've added both `LEFT JOIN` from my initial query. However, this makes it possible to get the same booking multiple times again, so I re-added that `GROUP BY`. But that does not seem to impact the execution time. Or do you have a better approach?

Comment: @quick-brown-fox - I assumed that `UNION DISTINCT` would avoid the need for the `GROUP BY`.  I'm running out of ideas.  I hope you understand `LEFT JOIN`, `UNION`, etc and can experiment with other options.

Comment: To make it clear what I mean with filtering: It should be possible to add `WHERE` conditions on `flight_services` and `hotel_services` on the outer query. But it works with said `LEFT JOIN`s and `GROUP BY`  from my initial query. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @quick-brown-fox - Be aware that `LEFT join x ON x.a=1` acts differently from `LEFT join x on... WHERE x.a=1` -- the latter turns `LEFT` into `INNER`.